# Java.util.logging. SetLevel has no effect on a custom Handler

Tags: java, logging

in the following code example the handler does not repect the call to setLevel.

```
Logger globalLogger = Logger.getLogger("");

Handler handler = new LogMailHandler();

handler.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);

globalLogger.addHandler(handler);

Logger local = Logger.getLogger(LogMailHandlerTest.class.getName());

local.severe("Test message severe...");
local.info("Test message info...");
```

LogMailHandler is defined as follows:

```
public class LogMailHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord pRecord) {
        System.out.println("Error registered..." + pRecord.getLevel().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Jan 19, 2015 5:20:33 PM com.idmedia.fts.exchange.helper.LogMailHandlerTest main
SEVERE: Test message severe...
Error registered...SEVERE
Jan 19, 2015 5:20:33 PM com.idmedia.fts.exchange.helper.LogMailHandlerTest main
INFO: Test message info...
Error registered...INFO
```

In my opinion the "Error registered...INFO" should not be there since the level of the handler was set to SEVERE.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must test the LogRecord on publish method with `boolean isLoggable(LogRecord)` before printing on console. This method tests, among other things, if the LogRecord level is higher that the minimum (in your case SEVERE)